# BATS - how to get a consistent UUID in my example?

Tags: bats-core

This is a bats test script I wrote

```
    export UUID=$(openssl rand -hex 6)
    export TEST_NAME=SecretsManagerTest1-$UUID

    setup_file() {
       echo "test name is $TEST_NAME" > setup.txt
    }
    
    @test "addition using bc" {
       echo "test name is $TEST_NAME" > runtest.txt
    }
```

I want $TEST_NAME to have the same value in setup.txt and runtest.txt but they have different UUIDS(same prefix - SecretsManagerTest1)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

When `bats` runs a test suite, it executes a file [multiple times](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/wiki/Bats-Evaluation-Process), once per test, since each test has its own shell, and once for `setup_file`.

This in turn means, that the whole file will be `source` several times, executing the "free code" outside any functions each time.

If you want to retain the same UUID for all tests in a `.bats` file, you should move the UUID generation into `setup_file`. Note that `setup_file` variable that should be visible to the tests must be `export`ed, since the tests run in a subshell.